# Select result from table for matching 2 rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a *MySQL* table has these fields

```
 ID, CID, QUESTION, ANSWER, USER
```

**ID** is auto increment, every record in table has **ID**;
 
**CID** is point to **ID** for *ANSWER* records

For example, we have 4 records, 2 of question 2 of answer, and Mike answers 2 questions

```
ID  CID  QUESTION  ANSWER         USER
1    0   Test      NULL           John
2    1   NULL      This is Test   Mike    
3    0   Example   NULL           Tracy
4    3   NULL      Yes it is      Mike
```

I want to list questions of which is Mike's answers. How can I match **ID** and **CID** fields in same table and print **QUESTION** for output

Comment: Have you tried to do an inner join with the same table?

Comment: Question and Answer really should be seperate tables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to list questions of which is Mike's answers.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM TableName t1
LEFT JOIN TableName t2 ON t1.ID = t2.CID
WHERE t2.Answer IS NOT NULL
  AND t2.User = 'Mike';
```

### [SQL fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce9bc/2)

Note that this gives you the list of questions that Mike has answered therefore you won't find mike listed on them:

```
ID CID     QUESTION         ANSWER  USER
1   0        Test             NULL   John
3   0       Example           NULL   Tracy
```

Comment: Doesn't filter on User = 'Mike'

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Sorry, fixed now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select QUESTION from yourtable 
where ID in(select ID from yourtable where User = 'Mike' and answer is NOT NULL)
```